# Apache rewrite rule which allows only one query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, drupal, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I have website at the root of the server

In a subfolder called se i have an installation of drupal, so going to

`https://websiteUrl/se`

launches drupal. I want only one page of drupal to be accessible and that all other tries go (not changing url so internally please) to this drupal accepted page. This aboslute page url is:

/se/?q=node/555 (se/index.php/?q=node/555 should aussi be rewriten as /se/?q=node/555 )
Other urls that should be rewriten are like se/index.php/?q=string )

i'am fighting with my apache conf file and Directory directive to do that.

here is my httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/se/>
AllowOverride None
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=node/[^555] [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([a-z]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /se/index.php?q=node/555 [L,R]
</Directory>
```

which is Ok for url like index.php?q=node/347 but not ok for index.php?q=searchString. All what i tried to do with a condition where i try to exclude the q=node/555 resulted in a infinite loop or inner javascript / css links being rewritten too (--> bad link)

Thanks !